# Error While Sending byte array serialy using Serial.write

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

Error While Sending byte array serialy using `Serial.write`.

```
     byte buf[] = {125, 126, 127, 2000, 5000};

 int i = Serial.write(buf, sizeof(buf));

 for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0])); i++)
     {
          Serial.println(buf[i]);
     }
```

output :

```
}~??125
126
127
208
136
```

Any while for Unknown charcters at start. I am using Arduino 1.0.5 version

Comment: Please what exactly do you want to tell us here: "*... Any while for Unknown charcters at start ...*"?

Comment: Any idea for getting unknown charcters at start....

Answer (score 2):

They are not Unknow characters, that's what you printed with:

```
int i = Serial.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Just check an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) `buf[0] = 125 = '{'`

With `write()` you are writing raw data without any kind of format. Your first byte is the value 125, in binary `01111101`. This byte correspond to the character `{` if it is intepreted as char. Your serial communication interprets the incoming byte as char, so it prints '{`.

If you want to print `125` as string on a serial communication, you have to send `buf[] = {49, 50, 53}`. Or you have to convert your interget into a string.

Answer (score 0):

what's also wrong is that you are using the `byte` type with values higher than 255. Try changing to `int16_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Characters at the start is the ASCII representation of the buff numbers you send. The arduino serial monitor monitors all the activities, and it prints out also your .write commands. .writeln which you do later, gets printed additionally after the original .write.

So what you see, is the ASCII representation of arduino sending your commands.

PS:
The numbers 2000 and 5000 don't fit into the byte, so the last two bytes that you send are probably corrupted.